# Using image from private repo in Docker Hub as a docker cloud agent template in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, devops, dockerhub

I'm trying to use image from private repo in Docker Hub as a Docker Agent template image. Added username/password credentials in registry authentication for Docker Hub in Jenkins. Restricted the label expression in freestyle item project to be this agent - the name matches the cloud. But each time i build it is always pending - saying it doesn't have label that called.

I've tested the private image locally - it works. While using image from public repo it works seamlessly. Can it be problem of Jenkins or Docker Hub? Is there a way to troubleshoot this?